# How to use RETURN_VALUE parameter in 'Create proc as EXEC' in Sybase?

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I'm trying to prepare stored procedure with `TDS_DYN_PREPARE` like

```
'create proc dyn1 as EXEC @RETURN_VALUE = sel_from_emp'
```

If I trying to use statement as is error `'Must declare variable '@RETURN_VALUE'`
If parameter name replaced with `?` (required for input params, but I tried on return value too) error 
`'The untyped variable ? is allowed only in in a WHERE clause or the SET clause of an UPDATE statement or the VALUES list of an INSERT statement'`

Is it possible to use return value in such statement and if yes - how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing here is executing a proc named sel_from_emp which apparently returns a status value (ASE procs can do that). Is this what ypu expected?
This status value is captured in variable @RETURN_VALUE -- but that variable is not declared,  so you must add a statement DECLARE @RETURN_VALUE INT.
Note that capturing the proc return statis mskes sense pmly when you sre going to do domething with that value, otherwise you can you do EXEC sel_from_emp.

Comment: I can't Declare in TDS_DYNAMIC token (where TDS_DYN_PREPARE is type, see Sybase-tds38 pdf). And can't describe through TDS_PARAMFMT due to server returns me parameters used.